# Does linux have HOST file?

Tags: linux

In windows I could find them in `windows/system32/driver/host`

Do linux have the same file? If yes what is the name and where is the path?

Thanks.

> Windows copy from linux? Is this true?

Comment: try to search once on internet , first result will give appropriate answer.

Comment: @RachitJain write one answer, you could get +1 vote up :')

Comment: Earnings point is really good(i do like to earn as many) but we should never leave behind the basic purpose of this forum (to help solving problems) and also precious time of experts/people involved here. I always challenge myself most before posting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file can be found at `/etc/hosts`. Note that you will need to use `sudo` to edit it, this is because the hosts file permissions allow it to only be writable as the root user.

Answer (score 2):

It does, located at - 
/etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

/etc/hosts

actually windows "copy" that from linux

Comment: And Linux copied it from UNIX.